# jQuery validator plugin not catching the submit action

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Basically, when I click submit, it sends me to the next page instead of preventing the post. It's not even validating anymore, so that needs to happen too. How would I go about fixing this?

Javascript:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/css">
jQuery.validator.addMethod(
  "noStateSelected",
  function(value, element) {
    if (element.value == "")
    {
      return false;
    }
    else return true;
  },
  ""
  );

  jQuery.validator.messages.required = "";


  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#newMemberForm").validate({
        invalidHandler: function(e, validator) {
            var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
            if (errors) {
                var message = errors == 1
                    ? 'You missed 1 field. It has been highlighted below.'
                    : 'You missed ' + errors + ' fields.  They have been highlighted below.';
                $("div.error span").html(message);
                $("div.error").show();
            } else {
                $("div.error").hide();
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function() {
            $(#newMemberForm).submit();
        },
        errorLabelContainer: "#messageBox",
        wrapper: "li",
        onkeyup: false,
        submitHandler: function() {
            $("div.error").hide();
            $("label.error").remove();
        },
        rules: {
            sponsor: "required",
            username: "required",
            password: "required",
            first_name: "required",
            last_name: "required",
            phone_number: "required",
            tax_id: "required",
            address_1: "required",
            city: "required",
            postal_code: "required",
            profile_stateList: {
                noStateSelected: true
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            terms_conditions: "required"
        },
        messages: {
                email: {
                    email: "Your email address must be in the format of name@domain.com ."
            },
            terms_conditions: "You must agree with the conditions."
        }

    });
  });
  </script>
```

HTML:

```
<form name="newMember" id="newMemberForm" action="~secure_url~/cgi-bin/xflow/newuser.cgi" method="POST"> 
 ....
 [Conditional input text box required if it exists]
 ...
</form>
```

Comment: Are you seeing any javascript errors?

Comment: type="text/css"> has been fixed to say text/javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My stupid issue, I made the type text/css. It has been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You have a bad selector on your sumbit action (You are missing quotes):

```
    submitHandler: function() {
        $(#newMemberForm).submit();
    },
```

Should be:

```
    submitHandler: function() {
        $("#newMemberForm").submit();   // Quotes here
    },
```

Comment: Thanks, that did not fix the issue though, still posting instead of catching the submit.

Comment: Why are you calling `submit()` anyway?  Isn't that the default submitHandler?

Comment: Oh, I just read your bug of `text/css`.  Funny, I saw that, and changed it in my test code, but I didn't think to mention it... oh well.